# How the equality in the first case is equivalent to the inequality in the last case?

Tags: elliptic-curves

The motivation to this question can be found in:

[About equivalent statements of the Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer Conjecture](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/125050/about-equivalent-statements-of-the-birch-and-swinnerton-dyer-conjecture?rq=1)

My question is about the last equivalences:

$\mathrm{ord}_{s=1} L(E/K,s) = \mathrm{rank} (E/K) \iff |Ш| < \infty \iff 
|Ш_l^{\infty}| < \infty$ for some $l \iff \mathrm{ord}_{s=1} L(E/K,s) \leq \mathrm{rank} (E/K)$

How the equality in the first case is equivalent to the inequality in the last case? Is this true for curves over rationals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows (for $A/K$ an Abelian variety over a function field or even for $K/\mathbf{F}_q$ finitely generated) since one always has $r_{\text{an}} \geq r$ ($r_{\text{an}}$ the analytic order $\mathrm{ord}_{s=1}L(A/K,s)$, and $r$ the rank of $A(K)$).

I proved this in my PhD thesis, which will be available in a few months.

Comment: @ Timo Keller: But it is not true for curves over rationals.

Comment: @Shpigle: In the thread "About equivalent statements of the Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer Conjecture", it is said that "When $K$ is a function field over a finite field of +ve characteristic,"

Comment: @ Timo Keller: Can you please indicate to me the title of your PhD thesis or the possible form for a paper citation.

Comment: @Shpigle: Please wait a few days.

Comment: It is on arxiv now, see http://arxiv.org/abs/1410.5294 (see also http://arxiv.org/abs/1410.5293).

Comment: @  Timo Keller: Thank you very much . I will read it now.